# Passing more than one props to one component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I pass more than one props to one component?

For example, I want to render a DIV that has various elements but not all the elements are in the same component.

So here I'm passing the whole component into another component, the problem with this is that ContentSkuInfo component is mapping throw states so all the data is loading in the same place, I need to load de data but ones in each DIV.

I need this:

```
<div>
<strong>Data 01</strong>
</div>

<div>
<strong>Data 02</strong>
</div>

<div>
<strong>Data 03</strong>
</div>
```

But I'm having this:

```
<div>
<strong>Data 01</strong>
<strong>Data 02</strong>
<strong>Data 03</strong>
</div>
```

This are my components **Seccion_uno_contenido.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ContentSkuInfo from './CallDataStorage';

const ContenidoUno = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="contentBox outerBox-first" >
      <a href={props.link}>
        <img src={props.imagen} alt="bloque 01" className="img-wrap" />
      </a>
      <h3>{props.categoria}</h3>
      <img src={props.icono} className="iconic" alt="producto" />
      <span>{props.descripcion}</span>
      <ContentSkuInfo />
      <small>Antes: ${props.antes}</small>
      <div className="containerBotonRow">
        <a href={props.link}><button className="botonRow">¡Lo quiero!</button></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ContenidoUno;
```

**CallDataStorage.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

var productsIds = ['3552357', '2635968BC', '3181464', '3593754'];
var productsIdsJoin = productsIds.join('-');

const getProductDetailAPI = (productsIds, storeId) => ({
    method: 'GET',
    baseURL:`SORRY CAN'T SHOW THIS`,
    auth: {
        username: 'XXXXXXX',
        password: 'XXXXXXX',
    },
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    data: {},
});

const ContentSkuInfo = (props) => {
    return (
        <strong>$ {props.prodsNormal}</strong>
    );
}

class DataStorage extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { products: [] };
    };

    getWebServiceResponse = (currentList, storeId) => (
        axios(getProductDetailAPI(currentList, storeId))
            .then(response => response.data)
            .then(newData => {
                this.setState({ products: newData.productDetailsJson })
            })
            .catch(e => e)
    );

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getWebServiceResponse(productsIdsJoin, 96);
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <samp>
                {this.state.products.map(skuData =>
                    <ContentSkuInfo
                        prodsName={skuData.name}
                        prodsId={skuData.productId}
                        prodsStatus={skuData.status}
                        prodsPublished={skuData.published}
                        prodsNormal={skuData.NORMAL}
                        prodsCMR={skuData.CMR}
                        prodsAhorro={skuData.savings}
                        prodsCombo={skuData.combo}
                        prodsStock={skuData.stockLevel}
                    />
                )
                }
            </samp>
        )
    }
}

export default DataStorage;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change the definition of `ContentSkuInfo` in CallDataStorage.js to

```
const ContentSkuInfo = (props) => (
  <div>
    <strong>$ {props.prodsNormal}</strong>
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing any props to ContentSkuInfo component in your code. To access something via props inContentSkuInfo you need to pass some properties to ContentSkuInfo.

For eg

When you are calling  ContentSkuInfo In your ContenidoUno component you need to send something like below

```
     <ContentSkuInfo prodsNormal=“testing”  prodsNormal2=“test2”/>
```

And in ContentSkuInfo component you can get it like remove $ from expression

Without return

```
     const ContentSkuInfo = (props) => (
         <div>
             <div>
                  <strong>{props.prodsNormal}</strong>
             </div>
             <div>
                  <strong>{props.prodsNormal2}</strong>
             </div>
          </div>
      )
```

With return

```
      const ContentSkuInfo = (props) => {
         return (
               <div>
             <div>
                  <strong>{props.prodsNormal}</strong>
             </div>
             <div>
                  <strong>{props.prodsNormal2}</strong>
             </div>
          </div>
          )}
```